# Pandas: Return Hour from Datetime Column Directly

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Assume I have a DataFrame `sales` of timestamp values:

```
timestamp               sales_office
2014-01-01 09:01:00     Cincinnati
2014-01-01 09:11:00     San Francisco
2014-01-01 15:22:00     Chicago
2014-01-01 19:01:00     Chicago
```

I would like to create a new column `time_hour`. I can create it by writing a short function as so and using `apply()` to apply it iteratively:

```
def hr_func(ts):
    return ts.hour

sales['time_hour'] = sales['timestamp'].apply(hr_func)
```

I would then see this result:

```
timestamp               sales_office         time_hour
2014-01-01 09:01:00     Cincinnati           9
2014-01-01 09:11:00     San Francisco        9
2014-01-01 15:22:00     Chicago              15
2014-01-01 19:01:00     Chicago              19
```

What I'd *like* to achieve is some shorter transformation like this (which I know is erroneous but gets at the spirit):

```
sales['time_hour'] = sales['timestamp'].hour
```

Obviously the column is of type `Series` and as such doesn't have those attributes, but it seems there's a simpler way to make use of matrix operations.

Is there a more-direct approach?

Comment: ``pd.Datetimeindex(sales['timestamp']).hour`` will be MUCH faster than using ``.apply``

Comment: This is the way I'll go. I was looking for a way to convert those columns to a datetimeindex-like object using `pd.to_datetime` iteratively. But the entire column itself needs to be a datetimeindex object, which isn't achieved with `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: you can do this with ``pd.to_datetime(column.values,box=True)`` as well (as somepoint I think will add a ``Series.to_index()`` method to basically do this directly. This is all vectorized.

Comment: @JohnE not sure where you are talking about

Comment: @Jeff -- ```Datetimeindex``` should be ```DatetimeIndex```, right? (capital I in Index)

Comment: you are right - can't edit the comments though :(

Comment: What if the column is not an index?

Comment: @nickpick I assume bunhae's answer would apply to index and non-index columns.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Assuming timestamp is the index of the data frame, you can just do the following:

```
hours = sales.index.hour
```

If you want to add that to your sales data frame, just do:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([sales, pd.DataFrame(hours, index=sales.index)], axis = 1)
```

Edit:
If you have several columns of datetime objects, it's the same process. If you have a column ['date'] in your data frame, and assuming that 'date' has datetime values, you can access the hour from the 'date' as:

```
hours = sales['date'].hour
```

Edit2:
If you want to adjust a column in your data frame you have to include `dt`:

```
sales['datehour'] = sales['date'].dt.hour
```

Comment: I unfortunately set my example up poorly. My actual conundrum includes several columns of `datetime` values. I'll be calculating elapsed _business hours_ between the timestamps, so will be extracting several sets of hour-unit values.

Comment: Assuming 'date' is a column `hours = sales['date'].hour1` will give an attribute error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'`  <br/>

Comment: @Lucas right, if it's a column then the answer would be hours=sales['date'].dt.hour

Comment: @famargar thank you so much adding dt save my life. What's the meaning of dt btw?

Comment: @overloading probably the abbreviation of `datetime`

Comment: I increasingly found that `pandas` just has too many layers to peel. It's not a straightforward search to know that you need to add `dt` to access a `datetime` column; and if it a column datetime string values, `dt` won't work either.

Answer (score 59):

For posterity: as of [0.15.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#v0-15-0-october-18-2014), there is a handy [.dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor) you can use to pull such values from a datetime/period series (in the above case, just `sales.timestamp.dt.hour`!

Comment: The link provided didn't work for me. This one did [.dt accessor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors).

Answer (score 19):

You can use a [lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful), e.g:

```
sales['time_hour'] = sales.timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.hour)
```

Comment: That's very helpful, especially if it turns out there's no way around using `apply()`.

Comment: It is true but it is slower than using `sales.timestamp.dt.hour`, and also slower to write

Answer (score 16):

You can try this:

```
sales['time_hour'] = pd.to_datetime(sales['timestamp']).dt.hour
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the quickest, shortest answer is in a comment (from Jeff) and has a typo, here it is corrected and in full:

```
sales['time_hour'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(sales['timestamp']).hour
```

Answer (score 1):

Now we can use:

```
sales['time_hour'] = sales['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
import pandas as pd
# convert the timestamp column to datetime
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# extract hour from the timestamp column to create an time_hour column
df['time_hour'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a function where, if needed, you could also extract month, year, etc. but 'timestamp' must be the index.

```
for i in range(len(sales)):
  position = sales.index[i]
  hour = position.hour
  month = position.month
  sales.loc[position, 'hour'] = hour
  sales.loc[position, 'month'] = month
```