# How to extract hours from a pandas.datetime?

Tags: python, pandas

I´ve a pandas dataframe which I applied the pandas.to_datetime. Now I want to extract the hours/minutes/seconds from each timestamp. I used df.index.day to get the days, and now, I want to know if there are different hours in my index.
For example, if I have two dates d1 = 2020-01-01 00:00:00 and d2 = 2020-01-02 00:00:00 I can't assume I should apply a smooth operator by hour because makes no sense.

So what I want to know is: how do I know if a day has different hours/minutes or seconds?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you checked the [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Return Hour from Datetime Column Directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129144/pandas-return-hour-from-datetime-column-directly)

Answer (score 9):

I think you should use df[index].dt provided by pandas.
You can extract day, week, hour, minute, second by using it.

Please see this.

```
dir(df[index].dt)
```

Here is an example.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["2020-01-01 06:31:00"], ["2020-03-12 10:21:09"]])
print(df)
```

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
df['dates'] = df['time'].dt.date
df['hour'] = df['time'].dt.hour
df['minute'] = df['time'].dt.minute
df['second'] = df['time'].dt.second
```

Now your df should look like this.

```
                     0                time       dates  hour  minute  second
0  2020-01-01 06:31:00 2020-01-01 06:31:00  2020-01-01     6      31       0
1  2020-03-12 10:21:09 2020-03-12 10:21:09  2020-03-12    10      21       9
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129144/pandas-return-hour-from-datetime-column-directly

Answer (score 1):

If `d1` and `d2` are [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) or [Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html#pandas-timestamp) objects, you can get the hour, minute and second using attributes `hour` , `minute` and `second`

```
print(d1.hour,d1.minute,d1.second)
print(d2.hour,d2.minute,d2.second)
```

Similarly, `year`, `month` and `day` can also be extracted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129144/pandas-return-hour-from-datetime-column-directly